# Does merging in class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty have a performance issue in CLI mode?

Tags: jmeter

We need to simulate automated third-party systems hitting our public APIs.  We don't want wait times between the the calls, because these are not humans that need to think but other computers which don't wait very long between actions.  I noticed that the script is taking longer than I would expect from the API call time totals.  After studying the debug logging I noticed that 'merging in class ...CollectionProperty' is taking anywhere from a few milliseconds to over 10 seconds using -n (CLI).  Is this expected behavior?  Configuration issue?  A performance bug?  This is occurring with JMeter "5.1.1 r1855137" on Windows 10.  Any ideas on a work around?

I tried running in GUI mode.  With a visualizer attached this operation usually took a few milliseconds (100 or less).  Max is about 3 seconds.  Without the visualizer in GUI mode 7 seconds seems to be the norm.

Notice the 7.5 second gap before the last operation:

```
2019-05-03 16:01:25,185 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: ResponseHeadersSize=786 Content-Length=2886 Total=3672

2019-05-03 16:01:25,185 DEBUG c.j.j.i.p.CompiledPath: Evaluating path: $['RunCreditCheckStatus']

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Existing HeaderManager '[HM] - SecuritySessionId,SubscriberId' merged with '[HM] - SecuritySessionId,SubscriberId:[HM] - SystemId DistributionChannelId Language'

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase:     CD-SessionId=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase:     CD-SubscriberId=355177

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase:     CD-SystemId=1ce731f0-33a6-4caf-b535-586fcf3bda60

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase:     CD-Language=en-US

2019-05-03 16:01:25,186 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: merging in class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty

2019-05-03 16:01:32,524 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function
```

Comment: can you show your test plan using menu tools > schematic view ? thx

Comment: It is large: https://pastebin.com/5j4A0ZNF